# react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem and I would like some help I have a Nav-bar component in which I use react-router-dom and react-transition-group for the routes of the pages and animate the transition between them and I have this warming (I attach an image with the error) I think it is causing it to declare element in Routes if so can someone tell me the right way? Thank you very much for your time.

CODE:

```
import {React, Fragment } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Link, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import { CSSTransition } from 'react-transition-group';
import Home from '../App';
import About from './About';
import Skills from './Skills';
import Proyects from './Proyect';
import Blog from './Blog'
import Contact from './Contact'

const routes=[
    { path: "/", name: "Home", Component: Home },
    { path: "/about", name: "About", Component: About },
    { path: "/skills", name: "Skills", Component: Skills },
    { path: "/proyects", name:"Proyects", Component: Proyects },
    { path: "/blog", name:"Blog", Component: Blog},
    { path: "/contact", name: "Contact", Component: Contact }
]




function Navbar(props) {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <ul className="ul-enlaces">
            {routes.map((route, index) => (
                <li  key={index} className={route.name}>
                    <Link
                    key={route.path}
                    as={NavLink}
                    to={route.path}>
                        {route.name}
                    </Link>
                </li>
            ))}
        </ul>
        <Routes>
            {routes.map((route, index) => (
                <Fragment key={index}>
                    <Route key={index} exact path={route.path} element={route.Component} >
                        {({match}) => (
                        <CSSTransition
                        in={match != null}
                        timeout={300}
                        classNames="page"
                        unmountOnExit
                        >
                        </CSSTransition>
                    )}
                    </Route>
                </Fragment>
            ))}
        </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
);
```

}

```
export default Navbar;
```

Warming :

```
Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of 
<Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.
at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:41517:5)
at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:41450:15)
at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:40259:5)
at Navbar
```

Image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9Ohi.png)

Comment: Did you try lower case "component" in your routes array

Comment: now what I did was to change the element={route.Component} to element={React.createElement(route.component, null, null)}
and now I have this Warming :  Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Comment: I mean here change it to (lowercase component).  Component seems like a reserved word:
const routes=[
    { path: "/", name: "Home", component: Home },
    { path: "/about", name: "About", component: About },
    { path: "/skills", name: "Skills", component: Skills },
    { path: "/proyects", name:"Proyects", component: Proyects },
    { path: "/blog", name:"Blog", component: Blog},
    { path: "/contact", name: "Contact", component: Contact }
]

Comment: if so, it changes to lower case and still comes out the same.